# du command show a slash after directories?

Tags: ubuntu, centos, filesystems, find, size

How to use `du` command show a slash after directories?

For example:

> du -ab /root/test/php-5.4.8/

Result:

```
1781    /root/test/php-5.4.8/main/internal_functions.c.in
973596  /root/test/php-5.4.8/main
3841    /root/test/php-5.4.8/netware/start.c
577     /root/test/php-5.4.8/netware/sendmail_nw.h
8514    /root/test/php-5.4.8/netware
4957    /root/test/php-5.4.8/README.TESTING2
4561    /root/test/php-5.4.8/.gitignore
```

However I want directories to include trailing slash, for example:

```
1781    /root/test/php-5.4.8/main/internal_functions.c.in
973596  /root/test/php-5.4.8/main/
3841    /root/test/php-5.4.8/netware/start.c
577     /root/test/php-5.4.8/netware/sendmail_nw.h
8514    /root/test/php-5.4.8/netware/
4957    /root/test/php-5.4.8/README.TESTING2
4561    /root/test/php-5.4.8/.gitignore
```

I have managed to do `find` command but it will not include total file size of the directories and that is why I have to use `du` command

```
find /root/test/php-5.4.8/ \( -type d -printf "%s %p/\n" , -type f -printf "%s " -print \)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just make it work with a little bash scripting. Print the size and filename, if it is a directory add a trailing slash.

```
du -ab | while IFS=$'\t' read -r size line; do printf "%s\t%s" $size "$line"; [[ -d $line ]] && printf "/"; echo; done
```

This will work with any file name not containing newlines or ending with a tab.

Comment: Thanks! What is `[[ -d $line ]]` ?

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back If exists and is a directory....

Comment: @Gilles Thanks for fix. Can you think of anything to improve the performance more?

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back Not without recompiling `du`. This should be I/O-bound anyway. Maybe changing the loop body to `if [[ -d $line ]]; then d=/; else d=; fi; echo -E "$size"$'\t'"$line$d"` will slightly speed things up if the output speed is the limiting factor because the file metadata is already in the cache.

Comment: Like this? `du -ab | while IFS=$'\t' read -r size line; if [[ -d $line ]]; then d=/; else d=; fi; echo -E "$size"$'\t'"$line$d"; done`

Comment: Note that `[[ -d $line ]]` (or POSIXly `[ -d "$line" ]`) checks whether `$line` is a directory **or a symlink to a directory** (which `ls -F` would output with the `@` instead of a `/`)

Comment: To optimize: do it in perl or any other shell than bash (which has the reputation of being the slowest shell of all). Also, the check if a file is a directory or not can be skipped when du has already reported files within it (if the previous line as `1234 ./foo/bar`, we know that `./foo` is a directory)

Comment: @gilles, it (the loop addition) is not likely to be I/O-bound. Since `du` will have done the `stat(2)` shortly before `bash`, the information is likely to be in cash, so it won't have to be retrieved from permanent storage. The main problem is bash `read` reading one character at a time, so a lot of `read(2)` system calls in addition to `stat(2)`. Using `perl` would make it a lot faster. Now, the whole thing is likely to be I/O bound but not much more than `du` alone.

Comment: @sch When I said “this should be I/O-bound”, I was obviously refering to the whole program: `du` would be the limiting factor for large hierarchies.

Answer (score 2):

My favorite trick with GNU `du`.

```
du -chs -- */ *
```

Since du excludes duplicates on command line arguments, it works, and print the slash automatically since you supplied the slash for folder.

Comment: That doesn't work as-is for directories that aren't at the toplevel. It does work if you change `*/` to `**/*/` (or `**/`, depending on your shell) (after turning on the `globstar` option in ksh or bash), but it may be slower because of the two recursive traversals. Also, the output won't be sorted in a sensible order.

Comment: It can be quite a memory hog, just reached over 70% mem usage on my 8GB machine for du **/'ing my home directory ...